# Query template in MS Access

Tags: sql, ms-access

Is there a way to create a reusable query template for below code, defining to change only the `WHERE` portion?

I have multiple queries which look the same except for the `WHERE .isCity`, `WHERE .isStreet`, `WHERE .isName` :

```
SELECT [TableA].word
FROM 
(
    (TableA INNER JOIN ATO ON [TableA].ID=ATO.ID) 
    INNER JOIN 
    TableB 
        ON TableB.word=[TableA].word) 
INNER JOIN CLA 
    ON CLA.[ID]=TableB.lang
WHERE [ATO].isCity;
```

which admittedly looks awful but, that's not the point.

Answer (score 4):

You can create a VBA procedure with your template SQL in a string variable, then use `Replace()` to substitute substrings as desired.  Here is an example from the Immediate window.

```vb
strTemplate = "WHERE [ATO].PLACEHOLDER"
? Replace(strTemplate, "PLACEHOLDER", "isCity")
WHERE [ATO].isCity
```